# Stored procedure execution issue on always on 3rd node

Tags: availability-groups

we have an alwayson three node setup. our client is executing a stored procedure on 3rd node. The stored procedure runs for 30 minutes and it is terminated and giving below error message without any results. Kindly assist on this

Msg 3949, Level 16, State 1, Procedure abc.def, Line 434 [Batch Start Line 0]
Transaction aborted when accessing versioned row in table 'abc.def' in database 'PROD'. Requested versioned row was not found because the readable secondary access is not allowed for the operation that attempted to create the version. This might be timing related, so try the query again later.

Completion time: 2023-07-04T08:44:39.3071725+04:00

Comment: What does [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) show that procedure is waiting on when you run it on the third replica server concurrently with the procedure running?

Comment: thank you @J.D. for the reply. we have insisted our client to run the stored procedure with correct parameter. Client was using wrong parameters while running the stored procedure and it fetched more than 3+ lakhs of records. The SP ran for an hour